# how to get soundcard output in Unity C#

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, soundcard

I have a unity program that takes a sound input from a mic and changes the gameplay based on ambient sound however I want to pipe the audio card output directly to the program instead so someone could be listening to music or whatever and that will change the gameplay. Is there any premade lld or easily importable libraries to Unity to do this? I was originally assuming that I could manipulate the way getting mic data works but unfortunately can`t.